# Cannot get ConcatRelated function (made by Allen Browne) to work

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use the ConcatRelated function (made by Allen Browne) in a simple way, but failing! I have looked at many, many Q&As on this site without success.

My Table (CCDS_Countries) has three fields:

1. Country_ID -- unique identifier (UID) for this Table
2. CCDS_ID -- UID for another table (CCDS_Data) with a 1-to-many relationship to this Table
3. Countries -- a field containing "EU", "US", or "UK".

This is sample data:

Country_ID  CCDS_ID Countries
1              0    US
2              1    EU
3              1    US
4              1    UK

Here's the output I want to see in a Query:

CCDS_ID Countries
0         US
1         EU, US, UK

Allen Browne's code is saved in the MS Access DB as "Module 2".

My Query has two output fields: [CCDS_ID] and my code:

=SELECT DISTINCT [CCDS_ID], (ConcatRelated("[Countries]", "[CCDS_Countries]", "[Countries]")) FROM [CCDS_Countries];

When I run the query, I get this error message: "The syntax of the subquery in this expression is incorrect. Check the subquery's syntax and enclose the subquery in parentheses".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, cannot have an SQL statement as a textbox ControlSource. If you want to do the concatenation in textbox on form then just call the function: `=ConcatRelated(...)`.

Secondly, WHERE condition criteria is not correct. Have to pass in CCDS_ID from each record so the function will know for which to accumulate related values. In query object, try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CCDS_ID, 
    ConcatRelated("Countries","CCDS_Countries","[CCDS_ID]=" & [CCDS_ID]) AS Countries
FROM CCDS_Countries;
```

Alternative query which might perform faster:

```
SELECT UID,
    ConcatRelated("Countries","CCDS_Countries","[CCDS_ID]=" & [UID]) AS Countries
FROM CCDS_Data;
```

If you want to do concatenation in textbox on form or report that is bound to CCDS_Data table:
`=ConcatRelated("Countries","CCDS_Countries","[CCDS_ID]=" & [UID])`

Comment: Thanks. I tried both ways, but still no success, and same error message.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: I want to use the outcome of the concatenation in a Query, rather than a form or report.

Comment: So why does your code show `=` sign in front of SQL statement? The queries I show work - I tested with tables.

Comment: The "=" was due to naivety. Even starting with a fresh database, and pasting exactly what you provided, I still get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was doing the basics wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The outcome is as expected when the code is pasted into "SQL View" it works as expected. I was putting the code into the "Design View" using the expression builder.